# Android service that starts at boot time and initiates a URI request to start another app

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, uri, autostart

I need to write a service that starts when the device is booted and initiates a URI to start another app. My research says I  must use a Broadcast receiver, but I am new to android. Please provide me some source code, or point me in a useful direction.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how to listen for Device boot complete action, receive broadcast message and initiate service.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".DeviceBootListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class DeviceBootListener extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(myService);
}
}
```